# Реализация функций внутри интерфейсов в C#

Tags: c#, методы, интерфейс

Открыл Visual Studio и Online C# Compiler.
В VS написал следующий код:

```
using System;

interface IGeometricShape
{
    void F()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
    }
}

class Rectangle : IGeometricShape
{

}

class HelloWorld
{
    public static void getInfo(IGeometricShape geometricShape)
    {
        geometricShape.F();
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        getInfo(new Rectangle());
    }
}
```

В Online C# Compiler написал такой же код, но проблема в том, что VS выдал мне следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А Online C# Compiler выдал ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как и почему так работает?

Comment: Постоянно слышал от всех, что интерфейс - это абстрактный класс, у которого ни один метод не реализован. Тут же интерфейс имеет реализованный метод.

Comment: Разные версии языка. В онлайн компиляторе более старая.

Comment: Почему в новом решили это добавить? Верно ли тогда утверждение, что реализацию метод в интерфейсе иметь не может?

Comment: начиная с C# 8 (если не ошибаюсь), интерфейсы могут много чего и, в частности, задавать реализацию методов по умолчанию. Эту реализацию можно изменить в наследнике

Comment: И интерфейс - это не `абстрактный класс, у которого ни один метод не реализован`. Абстрактный класс и интерфейс это разные вещи. Приведённое вами определение является "простыми словами, чтоб понять проще" и оно больше не актуально

Comment: Я понимаю, вставил определение из StackOverflow.
Но посыл везде один и тот же. Спасибо за ответ :)